# How can my API pick up my JWT Token information properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am working on the authentication portion of my application. A user is able to successfully register and login, with their information being stored in the SQL database. However, when I created a GetCurrentUser method in the UserController, the Endpoint is unsuccessfully picking up the users information.

Here is the login method where the token is generated:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLoginRequestModel loginRequest)
    {
        var user = await accountService.Validate(loginRequest.Email, loginRequest.Password);
        if(user == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized("Invalid Username or Password");
        }
        var token = GenerateJWT(user);
        var tokenValue = new { jwt = token };
        return Ok(tokenValue);
    }
```

Here is the GenerateJWT logic:

```
    private string GenerateJWT(UserLoginModel model)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, model.FirstName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName, model.LastName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, model.Email),
            new Claim("language", "english"),
        };

        if (model.DateOfBirth.HasValue)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Birthdate, model.DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString()));
        }

        var identityClaims = new ClaimsIdentity();
        identityClaims.AddClaims(claims);

        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["PrivateKey"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        var expire = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(configuration["ExpirationHours"]));
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var tokenDescription = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = identityClaims,
            Expires = expire,
            SigningCredentials = credentials,
            Issuer = configuration["Issuer"],
            Audience = configuration["Audience"]
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescription);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that this holds all of the information I need to get the currently logged in users information. See this screenshot:

[image]

Here is the endpoint to get the currently logged in user:

```
    [HttpGet("current")]
    [Authorize] // Add authorization attribute to ensure only authenticated users can access this endpoint
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrentUser()
    {
       // Retrieve the authenticated user's information from the JWT token's claims
        var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        var firstName = User.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName)?.Value;
        var lastName = User.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName)?.Value;
        var email = User.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email)?.Value;
        var dateOfBirth = User.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Birthdate)?.Value;

        var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");


        // Create a response object with the user information
        var currentUser = new CurrentUserModel
        {
            Id = int.Parse(userId),
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
            Email = email,
            DateOfBirth = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateOfBirth) ? DateTime.Parse(dateOfBirth) : null
        };

        logger.LogInformation($"JWT Token: {token}");

        return Ok(currentUser);
            }
        }
```

This is returning the correct ID, but all of the other information stored in currentUser is null.

What am I missing to get the current user from the stored JWT? I can post the angular code as well if that could be the culprit.

Comment: Look at your AccountController.cs  The bottom right view (output) show the SELECT being used.  You are getting null results because the SELECT is not returning any data.

Comment: How can I confirm what that SELECT is returning? The hardest part about debugging this weird issue is that the ID being returned is correct! Everything else is null.

Comment: Try using SQL Server Management Studio to see when is returned.  Also using SSMS the log file can be found in the explorer under Management.  Check the account/group that was used when you performed the query in asp.net.  Issue may be a permission issue or the USER may not contain data.

Comment: I wrote a related blog post at https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/ , perhaps it can help you?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is thyat the JwtRegisteredClaimNames claim names and the names in your user object does not match.

For example:

```
 var firstName = User.FindFirst(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName)?.Value;
```

What does JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName contain?

If you look in the source, its actually a URL
https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Claims/System/Security/Claims/ClaimTypes.cs,1f8b9c14a9b34152

It looks for a claim named:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/givenname
```

Its easier to use a string instead:

```
 var firstName = User.FindFirst("given_name")?.Value;
```

Comment: Super interesting! Thank you so much for this. Going to give it a try asap!